# Square-wise distance

Tags: geometry

I had a hard time finding a good title for this. Feel free to edit it if you find something more appropiate.

What I'm trying to do is finding a function such that, given a point $C$ (center), gives the square-wise distance from any point to $C$.

Now, for a simple definition of square-wise dist, imagine a square of a fixed size centered at $C$ and aligned to the $x$ and $y$ axis. I want each point of this square to be at the same square-wise distance from $C$, so it's the same as euclidean distance but changing circle by square.

How would I go into computing that? I can't wrap my head around it...

Comment: Hint: Consider each of the x-coordinate and the y-coordinate of the said two points.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_norm

Comment: @TheGreatSeo: It's taxicab geometry at a 45 degree angle.

Comment: @user2357112 It seems to be. I confused.

Comment: I'll have a look into that link. I didn't know this had a name! PD: Btw this is all related to a shader I'm writing, so when I get back home I'll edit my question and post a graphical representation of both euclidean distance and this distance with colors, I think that might also help to clearify my question for other readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $C = (x_c, y_c)$, and $P = (x,y)$, then: $$d(P,C) = \sup\{|x_c - x|, |y_c - y|\}$$
does the job.

Comment: sorry, what's sup? I assume it's the supreme of the set (idk if that's english) i.e. max, right?

Comment: That's right (:

Comment: Nice, thanks! Then that does the job. I just came to that thinking: Well, if the point lies whithin a square's perimeter the largest of the x and y coordinates must be the side of the square. Then I saw your answer, so it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You may like the following :

$$|(x-a)-(y-b)|+|(x-a)+(y-b)|=A$$
represents a square whose edge length is $A$ with the center $(a,b)$.

For example, see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7C%28x-4%29-%28y-2%29%7C%2B%7C%28x-4%29%2B%28y-2%29%7C%3D2).